# sending arguments to test script with istanbul

Tags: mocha.js, istanbul

I'm trying to see my [Mocha](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/) test code coverage with [istanbul](http://gotwarlost.github.io/istanbul/), but I need to supply the `--recursive` arguments to the test script `_mocha`, because else it only runs the tests in the **test** directory.

I tried `istanbul cover "_mocha --recursive"` but it says **Unable to resolve file [_mocha --recursive]**.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

it seems the following works:

`istanbul cover _mocha -- --recursive`

Comment: @HarryMoreno istanbul cover command expects `--` between the command name and the arguments to be passed: https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul#the-cover-command

Comment: Yes it worked, I could increase my coverage score on coveralls :)

@HarryMoreno in general `--` works on any unix command line, it means *end of command line options*.

Comment: @StLia You may need to pass in the proper path to the _mocha binary, e.g. node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha.